# How to set permission for 3 subfolder backwards after creating the directory in python

Tags: python, permissions

I would like to create a folder "C://user//Folder1//Folder2//Folder3//Folder4//Folder5//" in python.
"C://user//Folder1//Folder2" exists previously.

When I create the desire folder, I want to allow permission to all Folder3, Folder4 and Folder5.  While I don't want to affect the python's working directory which is located in another location "C://user1//python_script".

When I write the script, it only give full permission to Folder5 after creating desire__dir.

```
import os
desire__dir = "C://user//Folder1//Folder2//Folder3//Folder4//Folder5//"
if not os.path.exists(desire__dir):
    os.makedirs(desire__dir)
    os.chmod(desire__dir, 0o777)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) when working with paths:

```
import pathlib

desired_dir = pathlib.Path("C://user//Folder1//Folder2//Folder3//Folder4//Folder5//")
desired_dir.mkdir(parents=True)
```